# How can I run another project within my main Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, project, workspace

I have been working on a main project, and within that project there are a bunch of tabs that run different processes. However all those processes have been coded within the main project so this problem hasn't came up before.

Within one of the tabs we want to have a chat application that has already been created and tested within its own Xcode workspace.

How can I import the project and run it within the view when that tab has been selected?

Comment: did you try creating new targets?

Comment: Can you expand on your question?  I'm unclear if you're trying to get help organizing an Xcode workspace or manage tasks within your app.

Comment: @DustinPfannenstiel I'm trying to find out the correct way to import an application that was written as a separate project into the main project